# How to wrap Text in showModalBottomSheet?

Tags: dart, flutter

My widget tree looks like this:

```
showModalBottomSheet(... => WidgetTree()); // this symbolizes that I pass exactly what you can see below into the builder function

// WidgetTree
Row(
  children: [
    Text('some string') // if this string is long enough, it will overflow instead of displaying on a second line
  ]
);
```

[image]

*Above* you can see the *Modal Bottom Sheet*.
As you can see, the `Text` does not expand over the next lines, like it does in other scenarios, but I get a `RenderFlex OVERFLOWING` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [Wrap](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget:

```
// WidgetTree
Wrap(
  children: [
    Text('some string') // if this string is long enough, it will overflow instead of displaying on a second line
  ]
);
```

Comment: Awesome, I did not know about this widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this into a SingleChildScroolView with the scrollDirection to Axis.horizontal, like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: Row(
        children [Text("Some text")]
    )
);
```